# What does unmarked "teststeps" mean in Tosca Scratchbook?

Tags: tosca

My scratchBook log can be found in the picture underneath.

[image]

It opens the webbrowser, but does not close it (as I structured it to do). Therefore it does partly do what I wanted it to execute. However my real question is  why the "teststeps" in my scratchbook does not have neither approval or failing marks (see pictures below)?

[image]
[image]

Cheers

Comment: Appearently I have a "run-step-wise" mode on. This means that the teststeps are not run as a whole list, but rather separately. How to run the entire list is still a mystery for me.

Comment: Check here for more info: https://documentation.tricentis.com/en/900/content/tchb/test_execution.htm